# Building a Rails scope using `tap`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a method that looks something like

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.search(options = {})
    all.tap do |s|          
      s.where(first_name: options[:query])     if options[:query]
      s.where(graduated:  options[:graduated]) if options[:graduated]

      # etc there are many more things that can be filtered on...
    end
  end
end
```

When calling this method though, I am getting back all of the results and not a filtered set as I would expect. It seems like my `tap` functionality is not working as I expect. What is the correct way to do this (without assigning `all` to a variable. I would like to use blocks here if possible).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**`tap` will not work for this.**

- `all` is an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, a query waiting to happen.
- `all.where(...)` returns a *new* `ActiveRecord::Relation` the new query.
- However checking the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Object.html#method-i-tap) for tap, you see that it returns the object that it was called on (in this case `all`) as opposed to the return value of the block.

  i.e. it is defined like this:

  ```
  def tap
    yield self # return from block **discarded**
    self
  end
  ```

  When what you wanted was just:

  ```
  def apply
    yield self # return from block **returned**
  end
  ```

  Or something similar to that.

This is why you keep getting *all* the objects returned, as opposed to the objects resulting from the query. My suggestion is that you build up the hash you send to `where` as opposed to chaining `where` calls. Like so:

```
query = {}
query[:first_name] = options[:query]     if options[:query]
query[:graduated]  = options[:graduated] if options[:graduated]
# ... etc.

all.where(query)
```

Or a possibly nicer implementation:

```
all.where({
  first_name: options[:query],
  graduated:  options[:graduated],
}.delete_if { |_, v| v.empty? })
```

(If intermediate variables are not to your taste.)

Comment: Thanks for the awesome in-depth explanation!

Answer (score 5):

You can easily create a `let` function:

```
class Object
  def let
    return yield self
  end
end
```

And use it like this:

```
all.let do |s|          
  s=s.where(first_name: options[:query])     if options[:query]
  s=s.where(graduated:  options[:graduated]) if options[:graduated]

  # etc there are many more things that can be filtered on...

  s
end
```

The difference between `tap` and `let` is that `tap` returns the object and `let` returns the blocks return value.

Comment: I would also prefer to not monkey patch something like `Object`. Shouldn't calling `s.where(...)` modify the object that's getting the block was called on?

Comment: No - because `s.where` does not modify `s` itself! It's a purely functional methods which returns a new query object without modifying the existing one.

Answer (score 2):

These days (ruby >= 2.5) you can use `Object.yield_self`:

```rb
  def self.search(options = {})
    all.yield_self do |s|          
      s = s.where(first_name: options[:query])     if options[:query]
      s = s.where(graduated:  options[:graduated]) if options[:graduated]
      s
    end
  end
```

Comment: This works similar to #tap, continuing to keep method calls concise. Not sure why it was originally downvoted. Good use case for query objects